# Conditions in data input

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

im writing a simple app where you can input data to database through app. I have to make conditions for example: you can't put digits in Name field. I know I have to do this in onClick, but I dont really know how. Can you help me?

```
 public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.insertButton:
            dm.insert(editName.getText().toString(),
                    editAge.getText().toString(),
                    editSurname.getText().toString(),
                    editSex.getText().toString(),
                    editPesel.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.selectAllButton:
            showData(dm.selectAll());
            break;
        case R.id.searchButton:
            showData(dm.searchName(editSearch.getText().toString()));
            break;
        case R.id.deleteButton:
            dm.delete(editDelete.getText().toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For any sort of validation use Regular Expressions. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
You have to know this tool as developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the input to String in a try/catch, or set the input type to integer (use `android:inputType="number"` in your xml)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to do this in onClick.

`onClick` is perhaps not the ideal place as the user has already input the data and is therefore *after the fact*, as such.

Frequently it would be better to not allow *unacceptable(sic)* input when the user tries to enter such input.

There are alternatives, perhaps the simplest is to restrict the characters that can be input via the XML definition of the EditText e.g. to restrict to letters only then you could use :-

```
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

To allows spaces you could use (space added between lower and upper case) :-

```
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

---

However, really you should use a String Resource so you could easily cope with multiple languages (locales).

Therefore you could create a String resource (res/values/strings.xml) such as :-

```
    <string name="alphabet">"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"</string>
```

and then use :-

```
    android:digits="@string/alphabet"
```

---

Programatically (alternatively) you could use an `InputFilter` :-

```
    mAlphaBet = getResources().getString(R.string.alphabet);
    // Define the Input Filter
    InputFilter inputfilter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence s,
                                   int start,
                                   int end,
                                   Spanned dest,
                                   int deststart,
                                   int destend) {
            for (int i=0; i < end; i++) {
                // If not in the alphabet then suppress input
                if(!mAlphaBet.contains(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            // Indicate input is OK
            return null;
        }
    };
    // Apply filters (just the 1) to the EditText
    editName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{inputfilter});
```

- mAplhaBet is retrieved from the resources as above, again catering for locales if defined.